# How to find if out a user has jquery and display an alert if he/she doesn't

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am making a javascript library and I want to know how to find out if a user has jQuery on the webpage and display an alert if he/she doesn't. Can

```
if (!jQuery) { throw new Error("library_name requires jQuery") }
```

maybe work

Comment: I found another answer in the bootstrap javascript library that says:
`if (!jQuery) { throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery") }`

Comment: @VAGABOND I did not understand the answer of the question "Check if jQuery is included". I'm new in javascript and html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to do it in `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(!jQuery){
    //alert("!!!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (jQuery) {  
    alert("jQuery is loaded");
} else {
    alert("jQuery is not loaded");
}
```

If you're not using any other JavaScript libraries you can also check for '$' instead of 'jQuery'

To just alert if it's not loaded use:

```
if (!jQuery) {
     alert("jQuery is not loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check jQuery object exists or not

```
if (window.jQuery) {
   //yes its there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert("Jquery is not loaded");
}
</script>
```